# Custom keypad layout in Android

Tags: android, android-keypad, numeric-keypad

I have an EditText in my app that a user can enter a decimal Volume in.

At the moment i use:

```
EditText editTextVolume = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_vol);
editTextVolume.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

to get a numerical keypad. Is there anyway I can have this same keypad but with an extra button that is `*` or `x` so i can allow the user to input for example `4x200`.

I only want that one multiplication character (so no divide or other mathematical operators)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible without implementing your own custom keypad.

However, if your project requirements are not very strict, you may use `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`. This will allow putting `*` symbol, but will also make available several other symbols (e.g., `#`, `+`, `.`, `,`) used in phone numbers.